# Postgres. 're-index' with drop and create

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

We've got a pretty big and heavy used database where the indexes really need some cleaning up. What I wanted to use was the Reindex function, but this is not possible since 'Concurrently' is not supported and we cannot use a lock.

So what I came up with was to find all indexes, and for every index create a new temp_index (concurrently so there wouldn't be a lock). Then drop the old index and rename the temp_index to index.

Now I've hit another problem, while trying to drop the old index, postgres whines about constraints, and I have no idea how to solve this. These constraints ofcourse need to exist and be update or something to connect to the new index. And this is where I've hit the wall, I don't know how to solve this issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't drop and then create those constraints again, pointing to new index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example how this could be done:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (id integer CONSTRAINT tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY);
```

Now let's “`REINDEX CONCURRENTLY`”:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY tab_pkey_temp ON tab (id);

BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE tab DROP CONSTRAINT tab_pkey;

ALTER INDEX tab_pkey_temp RENAME TO tab_pkey;

ALTER TABLE tab ADD CONSTRAINT tab_pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX tab_pkey;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, we probably will be using some form of your code.

Comment: isn't `ALTER TABLE tab DROP CONSTRAINT tab_pkey;` blocking?

Comment: Sure, that's the idea.